# CSS Filter for Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: css

How can i make this CSS work in Mozilla Firefox?

```
.shadowed {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3));
    filter: drop-shadow(-1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3));
}
```

Also, no chances to get this working in IE, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the CSS Filter alternative for Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156116/whats-the-css-filter-alternative-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

IE has some different properties for this.

This is the msdn post for this: [DropShadow Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The code they used was:

`"filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(sProperties)" ... >`

It will be used by IE. For firefox I have used this for shadows.

`.someclass {

 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #00f;

 }`

You can read the documentation here: [hacks.mozilla.org](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/moz-box-shadow/)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer Box Shadow need extra elements...

Here is the HTML CODE BElOW

`<div class="shadow1">
    <div class="content">
        Box-shadowed element
    </div>
</div>`

Pls Check the jsfiddle which i make for this problem & its work in IE also

http://jsfiddle.net/eZygy/