# css filter invert() not working on mozilla firefox?

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, css-filters

I'm having an annoying issue with the css filter invert(); on Firefox 25.
This is the code, inserted inside jQuery .ready() context:

```
$('#colorcontrast').bind('click', function() {

        var css = 'html {'+
                    ' filter:invert(100%);' + 
                    ' -webkit-filter: invert(100%);' +                    
                    ' -o-filter:invert(100%);' + 
                    ' -ms-filter:"invert(100%)"; }';      

        if (!window.counter) { 
            window.counter = 1;
        } else  { 
            window.counter ++;
            if (window.counter % 2 == 0) { 
                css = 'html {'+
                    ' -webkit-filter:invert(0%);' +
                    ' -moz-filter:invert(0%);' +
                    ' -o-filter:invert(0%); }';
            }
        };

        console.log(css);

        $('#contrast').html(css);

    });
```

It works fine on Chrome and IE9, but not in Firefox 25.
When I visited its [doc reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#invert%28%29) using Firefox, I realized the live demo wasn't working!
Does anyone know something about? And could anyone point me other way or solution to apply such filter?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get used to checking support tables: http://caniuse.com/css-filters and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Filter support is now in Firefox 35! (Released January 13, 2015) :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may want to use a [SVG filter](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/svg.html). I basically a vector-shape graphic language which uses a XML structure. With this you can not only create vector shapes but also modifie different element. 
 I'm not sure how a SVG file does generate a specific effect(why it wouldn't support the normal invert(), but this one does support).

The xml file i used for this:

```
<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'>
  <filter id=\'invert\'>
    <feColorMatrix in='SourceGraphic' type='matrix' values='-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0'/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

The css + xml url i used:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'invert\'><feColorMatrix in='SourceGraphic' type='matrix' values='-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#invert");
```

I know the color isn't excactly the same as the original one, but it is an alternative.
Note this is just a 'hack' for firefox, you can just use static filters for other browsers.

---

More info about this subject:

[Latest version](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/)

[W3School tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_filters_intro.asp)

[Morzilla explenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content)

[a SVG generator online](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/hands-on-css3/hands-on_svg-filter-effects.htm).

[More info about SVG in Internet Explore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10.aspx)

---

You can't find all effects in the generator, but i might be usefull to see different structure with different effects. You might want to read some basic understanding of XML first :)

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D56SP/1/)**

---

Other topic about this matter: [What's the CSS Filter alternative for Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156116/whats-the-css-filter-alternative-for-firefox)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox [doesn’t support CSS filters yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). At all.

Also, you should be toggling a class, not dynamically creating stylesheets.

Comment: @nkmol: Yep! Only Chrome had trouble with those, if I recall correctly.

Comment: So what about using that to create a revert effect? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D56SP/). Though it may be lighter as a 'static' one, it is an alternative.

Comment: @nkmol: Liked! Same the colors... aren't inverted in final result. Where can I learn about this approach?

Comment: @minitech Thanks for the tip. I changed the script to only switch the class.