# Inverting and re-inverting element with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-filters

I want to invert and re-invert background image of the page (div) with a click on specific element. Now I have the script:

```
$(function(){
$(".invert").click(function(){
    $(".pattern").css({
    "-webkit-filter": "invert(100%)",
    "-moz-filter": "invert(100%)",
    "-o-filter": "invert(100%)",
    "-ms-filter": "invert(100%)"

    });
    $(".invert").addClass("reinvert");
    $(".invert").removeClass("invert");

});

$(".reinvert").click(function(){
    $(".pattern").css({
    "-webkit-filter": "invert(0%)",
    "-moz-filter": "invert(0%)",
    "-o-filter": "invert(0%)",
    "-ms-filter": "invert(0%)"

    });
    $(".reinvert").addClass("invert");
    $(".reinvert").removeClass("reinvert");
});
});
```

The invert function works fine, but it doesn't re-invert the element back.

I'd also like to make it work at least in Firefox and in other browsers if possible.

**Update:**
Changed code to:

```
$(function(){
$(".invert").click(function(){
    $(".pattern").toggleClass("inverted");
    $(".invert").css("display", "none");
    $(".re-invert").css("display", "inline");
});
$(".re-invert").click(function(){
    $(".pattern").toggleClass("inverted");
    $(".re-invert").css("display", "none");
    $(".invert").css("display", "inline");
});
});
```

With CSS:

```
.inverted {
filter: invert(100%);
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
-moz-filter: invert(100%);
-o-filter: invert(100%);
-ms-filter: invert(100%);
}
```

Which works fine (at least the way I wanted) in Chrome, but still looking for any way to make it work the same in Firefox. Thank you guys for help, sorry I don't have enough reputation to rate answers.

Here's the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/5AdxC/1/

**Update 2:**
It seems like I found a way to make it work in Chrome and Firfox, but didn't test it with Opera or IE. http://jsfiddle.net/5AdxC/2/

CSS option for Firefox:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'invert\'><feColorMatrix in='SourceGraphic' type='matrix' values='-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#invert");
```

Comment: can you make fiddle for this

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5AdxC/

Comment: I've tried both 100% and 0% it doesn't re-invert anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as-is is working just fine!

See this fiddle with your code: **http://jsfiddle.net/K5NJy/1/**

Perhaps, the problem lies where you are swapping classes on the `.invert` and `.reinvert` element(s):

```
$(".invert").addClass("reinvert"); // perhaps this is causing unwanted behavior
$(".invert").removeClass("invert"); // perhaps this is causing unwanted behavior
```

*And as @Shivan said*, this will work only on webkit based browsers. Others do not support filter in this form.

**Edit**: (*after your requisites of Firefox or Opera*)

See this updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/K5NJy/5/**

This updated fiddle will work in **Chrome, IE9 and Firefox**. (I don't have Chrome installed so can't check, but webkit based browsers should anyway support it).

As mentioned above (and also by @Shivan), Firefox (Gecko) supports only the `url()` way of filters. So you need an SVG/XML map for that to work.

I lifted Firefox bit of code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19691142/1355315

Also, note that the order of the application of css in your code will affect IE9 and Firefox. Whichever way of filter is applied last will hold. So, if `url()` one is applied last, it will work in Firefox but not in IE. So, you will have change that in fiddle to check.

Moreover, for older IE (<9) you will need to use `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Invert`, which is deprecated in IE9 and above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my code a bit and it's working the way I wanted. I actually knew that it doesn't work in Firefox or Opera from the beginning, that was the part of my question.

Comment: @Kostsei I have updated my answer. Please see the edit. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K5NJy/5/

Comment: Thanks! I've just used the code from the same topic(: I don't care much about IE — can't imagine why someone still use it.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox, Gecko currently only implements the `url()` form of the filter property;  . IE 4-9 has another syntax of filter.

No such thing called `-moz-filter`, `-ms-filter` and `-o-filter` according to specification.

Reference: [filter at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: I've copied these properties from other topics on Stackoverflow, although I know that there are no such specifications, I've seen lots of examples including those parameters, so I left them as they were. Still I don't understand how can I apply that thing for Firefox. I should have some code in html and some in CSS? Could you give me an example of code, please?

Comment: follow the specification ONLY. Codes in other posts may not be error-free. Read the reference link for example.

Comment: Yes, I've read the article you provided, but I'm not a professional coder and I'm new to SVG-related stuff, so I'm afraid that I need a full example of code to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Why have a **'.invert'** AND **'.reinvert'** when you can just `toggle()`?

Makes your code super easy, anyways [here is my version](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/PtQwV/) of inverting only the bg and keeping everything else static within.

Also, instead of doing inline css, why not create classes in your stylesheet for the inverted, so the 'reverted' just does not use that class with the toggle effect? Makes the code more professional :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've made it work for Chrome, a bit different, but with toggle. But I want an option for Firefox also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".reinvert").click(function(){
    $(".pattern").css({
    "-webkit-filter": "invert(100%)",
    "-moz-filter": "invert(100%)",
    "-o-filter": "invert(100%)",
    "-ms-filter": "invert(100%)"

    });
    $(".reinvert").addClass("invert");
    $(".reinvert").removeClass("reinvert");
});
```

With this , you'll be applying the filter to 100% again , there by going back to the original.

Comment: Thank you, I've already change it to:
`$(function(){
 $(".invert").click(function(){
  $(".pattern").toggleClass("inverted");
  $(".invert").css("display", "none");
  $(".re-invert").css("display", "inline");
 });
 $(".re-invert").click(function(){
  $(".pattern").toggleClass("inverted");
  $(".re-invert").css("display", "none");
  $(".invert").css("display", "inline");
 });
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by clearing the filter:

```
$(".reinvert").click(function(){
    $(".pattern").css({
        "-webkit-filter": "",
        "-moz-filter": "",
        "-o-filter": "",
        "-ms-filter": ""
    });

    $(".reinvert").addClass("invert");
    $(".reinvert").removeClass("reinvert");
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ad4mD/.