# invert filter in IE11

Tags: html, css

Is there any chance to use a **invert-css filter** in **Internet Explorer 11** ? I already tried the following css-commands :

```
-ms-filter: Invert(); // also with the parameters '1' and '100%'
filter: Invert();

-ms-filter: invert();
filter: invert();
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: IE does not yet support `filter`, even prefixed.

Comment: Is there any workaround for the missing filter ?

Comment: IE used to have its own, proprietary "DX filters" but they were dropped a while ago. Searching (here & Google) for polyfills doesn't produce many promising results but you may want to try that.

Comment: I tried the DX filters already ... but thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: try a [SVG filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686153/css-filter-invert-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox/19691142#19691142)

Comment: @nkmol can you give me an example or an code snippet for the given problem ?

Comment: @nkmol ... does not work ... :-/

Comment: Funny, filters work in ie9 but not in ie10 or 11. At least in emulation mode. I was targeting IE9 as the lowest supported and was using filters everywhere.  Since it worked in ie9 I didn't think I was going to have any issues.