# how to make css filters work in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am good with HTML5 and CSS but i've never used filters before. So i was applying some fiters using Jquery and they worked fine with Chrome however nothing happened when i tried to apply them in firefox.

Jquery code

```
$('#grayscale').click(function() {
    $('#uploadedPhoto').css('-webkit-filter', 'grayscale(100%)');   
});

$('#sepia').click(function() {
    $('#uploadedPhoto').css('-webkit-filter', 'sepia(100%)');   
});
```

These are just two examples. 
I have searched for this and found that Firefox doesnt support simple `filter:` syntax yet and there is some other way with URL and SVG. Can you please give an example or a link to the library of the specific filter URLs. For this URL method do i have to link some library first like with Jquery?

Thank You

Comment: You would need to use a non-webkit prefix and FF does not support -webkit-prefixes. Try `-moz-filter`.

Comment: @Paulie_D you're right in general, but Firefox just doesn't have support for anything other than grabbing SVG filter definitions from a URL.

Comment: You could use JS to achieve the same thing, it just won't be as efficient at doing it.

Comment: It looks as if Firefox 34 will support CSS `filter:` directly, see [Bugzilla bug 948265](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=948265).

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not support CSS-Filter (yet?). 
Source: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/#browser-support 
EDIT (to answer the new question): I found a stackoverflow post that discusses alternatives for css filter in order to support firefox: [What's the CSS Filter alternative for Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156116/whats-the-css-filter-alternative-for-firefox)

Comment: You can check this at a site like [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=css-filter).

Comment: This is a correct statement but it does not actually answer the question

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot use filters in firefox yet.

A workaround would be to create a file name `filters.svg` with the following contents:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="grayscale">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="sepia">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.343 0.669 0.119 0 0 0.249 0.626 0.130 0 0 0.172 0.334 0.111 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 "/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

And then use the following styles (the url to the svg should be relative from the css file to your svg file you just created):

```
.greyscale {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: grayscale(100%); /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

.sepia{
    filter: url(filters.svg#sepia); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: sepia(100%);
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}
```

With the following js

```
$('#grayscale').click(function() {
    $('#uploadedPhoto').addClass('greyscale');   
});

$('#sepia').click(function() {
    $('#uploadedPhoto').addClass('sepia');    
});
```

[Here is a good resource showing different filter effects using svg](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/tutorials/smarter_svg_filters)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609273/convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-html-css) has a [good example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11137205/grayscale.html) of how to use an svg

If you want to play around with the colours then you will need an understanding of [this tutorial](http://www.svgbasics.com/filters4.html) with [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Ordinary_matrix_product)

Comment: i should create a simple textfile and name it .svg? or is it xml file or javascript

Comment: It's an svg file - in the form of xml (but has an svg extension)

Comment: This also works with inline SVG. There is no need for a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

The `-webkit-filter` contains the prefix `-webkit` which is only supported in webkit engine based browsers, such as Safari and Chrome. The prefix for Firefox is `-moz` for Mozilla, but Firefox doesn't support this property.

Read more here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: That article further explains that `filter:` is not supported by Firefox or IE.