# Alternative for -webkit-filter in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

I was reading this page on stackoverflow: **[Change color of PNG image via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415872/change-color-of-png-image-via-css)**. I was reading the reply by ravitadi, and he said you could change your pictures color with -webkit-filter.

My question is how could I use -webkit-filter in Mozilla Firefox. As you know -webkit-filter would not work there, so is there a alternative CSS property to use instead? I know this works in Chrome, but I need this to work in all browsers! :)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156116/whats-the-css-filter-alternative-for-firefox

Comment: @Etash That question is asking about the now-obsolete non-standard `filter` property that was in IE. Same name, but no the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), without the `-webkit-` prefix. [It will work in Firefox 35 and up.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) If you need support for older Firefox versions, look into SVG filters. MDN has an article entitled [Applying SVG effects to HTML content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content) on the issue.

Comment: Thank You! :) I did not know there was Filter

Comment: I forgot to ask, does this support Internet Explorer aswell?

Comment: @michaeljones No, IE does not support the standard `filter` property. It used to support a non-standard and completely different property by the same name, but it was not the same and was removed. I don't believe it's possible to use SVG filters for DOM elements in IE either.

Comment: Hmm ok! :) Any idea on what to use for IE?

Comment: @michaeljones Depends on what you are doing. If it's only being applied to images, canvas might be an option. You could also possibly wrap the image in an SVG with the filter.